# vb.net - click on a button, multiple buttons with same html code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Just joined here and started learning vb.net. I searched around, but didn't come across anything. Using Vb.net in Visual Studio with WebBrowser. I have a webpage with a button that I want to click on. The button is displayed 9 times, with the same code. So basically the identical button is displayed multiple times. When I create a function in vb.net to click on the button, it opens up all 9 at once. I would like to open only one at a time. I know in imacros you can get around this problem by assigning position 1, position 2, etc so it clicks on the first occurring one, then the second, etc. Is there a way to do this in vb.net? Thank you.

Here is the code that clicks the button(s)

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
TextBox7.Text = TextBox7.Text + 1

theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
If InStr(curElement.GetAttribute("value").ToString, "Visit") Then

    curElement.InvokeMember("Click")
    curElement.InvokeMember("MouseDown")
    curElement.InvokeMember("MouseUp")
    curElement.InvokeMember("OnClick")
    curElement.Focus()
End If

Next
Timer2.Interval = TextBox6.Text

End Sub
```

Here is the inspect element info of the buttons:

```
<input class="submit" value="Visit" style="width: 110px; height: 80px; border-radius: 40px; font-size: 27;" type="submit">
```

Comment: What do you mean "it opens up all 9 at once"?  How specifically does this loop behave and how does it differ from what you're trying to do?

Comment: There are 9 buttons with the same code, when I initiate the click event, 9 buttons are clicked and 9 windows are opened. Since the buttons are the same, this happens. Since I cannot differentiate the buttons based on tag, value, name, etc, the only way to distinguish them would be based on their position (I'm assuming). I am looking to only click one at a time. -Thanks for reply

Comment: Well, the code posted clicks all the buttons in a loop.  If you only want to click one button, then remove the loop and only click one button.  I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: If I try to click one, all buttons are clicked because they all have the same code. They are identical in html inspect element values and on the same page.

Comment: What do you mean by "they all have the same code"?  If they all do the same thing, why does it matter which one is clicked?  If they do different things, only click *one* of them (as in, don't use a loop over all nine of them).  If they're all truly identical, then in order to identify one of them you'll either need to add something to them to differentiate between them (such as an `id` attribute) or you'll need to assume their identity by their position in the array from `GetElementsByTagName` (which isn't necessarily reliable).

Comment: This is the code of the buttons:  
 <input class="submit" value="Visit" style="width: 110px; height: 80px; border-radius: 40px; font-size: 27;" type="submit">

They all go to different links which are random each time the page is loaded. Can't differentiate by id as it's the same. How do I identify them by position, seems like only option. -Thanks

Comment: You'd differentiate them by their position in the array by referencing a specific array element instead of looping over the entire array.  Basically, only click one button instead of all of them.  (Of course, if the action of the button as, as you say, *random*, then it probably doesn't matter which one you click...)

Comment: hmm, even if I am not using a loop, all buttons are clicked because they are identical.

Comment: How are they all clicked?  If the VB code only invokes a click event on one of them then only one will have its click event invoked.  It doesn't matter if they're identical, they are still separate DOM elements.  And DOM events are invoked on elements, not on the code which creates those elements.  When you debug this, where *exactly* does it fail?  Are they actually all clicked, or is only one clicked but they all have the same click handler?  You need to be specific.  The code posted in the question invokes the click event on every matching `input` element (even ones that aren't buttons).

Comment: Yes, all the buttons are clicked at once.

Comment: That's exactly what I am attempting to do, to invoke a click on one of them. I don't see how that is possible unless there is some way to use their position on the webpage as a data source, thus my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment above, you state:

> That's exactly what I am attempting to do, to invoke a click on one of them. I don't see how that is possible

Well, the code posted in the question is invoking the `click` event in a loop on all matching elements:

```
theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
    ' invoke the click handler
Next
```

If you want to invoke the `click` event on only one element instead of all of them, then don't use a loop:

```
theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
If theElementCollection.Count > 0
    ' invoke the click handler on the first element
End If
```

However, since not all of the elements returned by your query are the ones you're looking for, the quickest approach for the current code would likely be to just introduce an `Exit For` statement after the first target element is reached.  Something like this:

```
theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
    If InStr(curElement.GetAttribute("value").ToString, "Visit") Then
        curElement.InvokeMember("Click")
        curElement.InvokeMember("MouseDown")
        curElement.InvokeMember("MouseUp")
        curElement.InvokeMember("OnClick")
        curElement.Focus()
        Exit For ' right here
    End If
Next
```

That way the loop will stop iterating after the first matching element is "clicked".

Comment: Ah thanks David (Sorry for the question from hell)
The Exit For was what I was looking for.
Thanks a million!